# react setupProxy.js not working on build only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, proxy

setupProxy.js exists in src/ and it works great with 'yarn start' but it doesn't work when I build and serve react app.
Is there some other configurations needed for setupProxy.js to use it with build ?

- .env.development

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

- src/setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/api',{
            target: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

- How I built my app

```
env-cmd -f .env.development yarn build
```

- How I served my app

```
serve -s build
```

- request

  It's supposed to request to port 8080, but using 5000 which is react port. Seems like my react app is not recognizing setupProxy.js.

[image]

When api url was directly put into axios.create(), it worked perfectly so I guess it's only problem of setupProxy.js, not about loading env file.

```
axios.create({baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,});
```

Comment: I have this exact issue. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @TheMahahaj Can you have a look at the baseURL value axios.create? In my case, it used to have api path only and I changed it to include api url as well, and it was resolved. I hope it helps your case.